# Internet Explorer 6 and 8 onchange not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6, onchange

I am trying to populate some fields on a form using the onchange method of a select box.

```
<tr>
                <td align="left"><label>*Select Branch:</label></td>
                <td><form:select tabindex="5" path="userInputBranch" onchange="setProcessorBranchLocationOnChange()">
                        <form:option value="--" label="--" />
                        <form:options items="${ customerAddEntity.selectionContentsBranch}" itemLabel="key" itemValue="value" />
                    </form:select> 
                    <form:hidden path="autoUserInputProcessor" /> 
                    <form:hidden path="autoUserInputCompany" /> 
                    <form:hidden path="autoUserInputLocation" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

The Javascript function:

```
function setProcessorBranchLocationOnChange() {
var rawBranch = $('#userInputBranch').attr('value').split('-');
    $('#autoUserInputProcessor').attr('value', rawBranch[0]);
    $('#autoUserInputCompany').attr('value', rawBranch[1]);
    $('#autoUserInputLocation').attr('value', rawBranch[2]);
    if(rawBranch[3]!=null){
        var cBranch = rawBranch[3].split('=');
        $('#userInputBranch').attr('value', cBranch[1]);
    }
```

}

As you can see I am trying to populate the hidden fields, autoUserInputProcessor, Company, Location with a subString value of the selected drop down value.

This works fine in Chrome and IE7.  I am not getting any updates on the hidden fields in IE6 and IE8.  I am using spring's tag lib to generate the form.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if you need any additional information.

I am using jQuery 1.61.min.js with jQuery forms 2.4 and jQuery UI 1.8.

Here is some sample data from the select that is generated by Spring.

This is one of the options. ( I have no control over the format of the value, it is as I received it.)

```
    <option value="06-04-22-id=2504">Oneonta, NY</option>
```

This is an example of the fields populated.

```
<input id="autoUserInputProcessor" name="autoUserInputProcessor" type="hidden" value="06">
<input id="autoUserInputCompany" name="autoUserInputCompany" type="hidden" value="04">
<input id="autoUserInputLocation" name="autoUserInputLocation" type="hidden" value="22">
```

This is my complete javascript file that is loaded when the page loads:

```
    //window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

    function setProcessorBranchLocationOnChange() {
    var rawBranch = $('#userInputBranch').attr('value').split('-');
    $('#autoUserInputProcessor').attr('value', rawBranch[0]);
    $('#autoUserInputCompany').attr('value', rawBranch[1]);
    $('#autoUserInputLocation').attr('value', rawBranch[2]);
    if(rawBranch[3]!=null){
        var cBranch = rawBranch[3].split('=');
        $('#userInputBranch').attr('value', cBranch[1]);
    }

    }

$(function() {
// Set tab indicies that aren't available until load.
$('#customersearchanchor').attr('tabIndex', 120);
$('#logoutLink').attr('tabIndex', 125);

// Set the processor, company, location
// hidden fields on branch select change

setProcessorBranchLocationOnChange();

});
```

Comment: i have never seen that someone is writing HTML like that

Comment: You should make sure that IE6 is a real requirement -- no one uses it anymore

Comment: IE6 is a requirement unfortunately :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [jQuery's change function](http://api.jquery.com/change/)? It will likely handle some browser quirkiness for you.

```
$('.selectorForTheSelect').change(setProcessorBranchLocationOnChange);
```

Don't forget to remove the onchange attribute of the select in the HTML.

Comment: When I pass the function call to the change function do I need to specify the empty parameters, () ? (Just wondering because I did what you did and it didn't work.)

Comment: Ok, I got it working doing what you said, sort of. If I place the function call inside the change() method it doesn't work.  If I place the function in the change method it does work... like this.

Comment: `$('#userInputBranch').change(function(){    var rawBranch = $('#userInputBranch').attr('value').split('-');
        $('#autoUserInputProcessor').attr('value', rawBranch[0]);
        $('#autoUserInputCompany').attr('value', rawBranch[1]);
        $('#autoUserInputLocation').attr('value', rawBranch[2]);
        if(rawBranch[3]!=null){
            var cBranch = rawBranch[3].split('=');
            $('#userInputBranch').attr('value', cBranch[1]);
        }
        
        alert($('#autoUserInputProcessor').val());});`

Comment: Any ideas on how to make it work the other way, or why it is not working the other way?

Comment: It could be a scope issue. Is setProcessorBranchLocationOnChange a global function, or is it defined inside an object? If you posted all of your JS in the question then it looks global to me, in which case it should work. It doesn't use "this", so it wouldn't matter where it's called from. Have you tried sticking a breakpoint in Firebug or Chrome's dev tools and stepping through the execution?

Comment: I did it the lazy way, instead of figuring out the other problem I just inlined the function, committed the code and told the P.T.B. that the could roll to prod.

Comment: Thank you much for your time and effort and for fixing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, userInputBranch is not the id of the element
Second, use the jQuery's `.val()` function, instead of attr)'value');
And since you are already using jquery, use the `.change()` event.

Comment: userInputBranch is set as the id when using the path variable in Spring.